# Как сделать onclick окно с расширенной информацией о товаре?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

У меня есть [сайт-каталог](http://textiletoday.ru). Мне интересно, как сделать, чтобы при клике на товар всплывало окно с расширенной информацией о нём? И насколько это будет нагружено для сайта?

Comment: почитайте про `fancybox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нагрузка на сервер зависит от того, что вы хотите показать в этом всплывающем окне. В большинстве случаев контент простой и его можно подгрузить вместе со всей страницей, но, если очень много разных данных, лучше при самом клике.

Само модальное окно делается очень легко: просто создаётся слой поверх всего остального содержимого страницы с кучей CSS, как для расположения (вроде `position:fixed;`), так и для красоты (вроде затемнения основного контента, загружённых углов).

[Вот хороший пример](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) из Bootstrap, можно вырезать стили и использовать без него. Или, как подсказал @ThisMan, можно использовать библиотеки вроде *FancyBox*.

---

Ваш **план действий** таков:

- Создаёте JavaScript функцию, которая принимает какой-нибудь ID товара и показывает модальное окно. Для появления/исчезновения этого окна нужно менять стили слоя. Конечно, содержимое окна тоже нужно обновлять, либо заранее загруженными данными, либо делать для этого HTTP запрос.
- При заполнении HTML страницы товарами всем им в событие `onclick` ставите вышеупомянутую функцию с идентификатором текущего товара.